# python: Input() inside of a for loop error

Tags: python

```
for i in range(5):
    mylist[i]=int(input("Input an integer: "))
```

Do I really still have to define mylist before the for loop before I can actually use it?
At the first loop it works fine but at the second loop it will show a NameError
do I have to use a different inut method or what?

> NameError: name 'mylist' is not defined

Comment: Yes, you cannot index a variable that doesn't exist. Declare `mylist` ahead of the loop or you'll get `IndexError` and `NameError` problems

Comment: Hello And Welcome to StackOverflow Please show your full

Comment: Unless there's more code that you're not showing, it doesn't make sense to try to set or get something at an index of a list that has yet to be defined.

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to define what "mylist" is before you assign values to it.

```
mylist = []
for i in range(5):
    mylist.append(int(input("Input an integer: ")))
```

Comment: This will throw an `IndexError` - set the size beforehand, i.e. `mylist = [None] * 5`

Comment: use append method to add anything to list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to define the list before like this

```
mylist=[]
for i in range(5):
    mylist[i]=int(input("Input an integer: "))
```

Comment: As pointed out on TimTam's answer, this will throw an `IndexError` unless the size of the list is declared beforehand. This can be circumvented by using `.append()`, though

Answer (score 0):

you could just use list comprehension

```
mylist = [int(input("Input an integer: ")) for _ in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `mylist` before you assign values to it.

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(5):
    mylist[i]=int(input("Input an integer: "))
```

Or if you want to fill the empty list use `append()` list function

```py
mylist = []
for i in range(5):
    mylist.append(input("Input an integer: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you are needed to define the list before the loop
and also define the contents too, because it will throw a error
Note: here i used 0 you can also use keyword None

```
myList = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range(5):
    myList[i] = int(input("Enter a int: "))
```

or you could also use function append using this you don't have to define what does myList contains-

```
myList = []
for i in range(5):
    myList.append(int(input("Enter a int: ")))
```